# The login function in Django not working properly

Tags: python, html, django

**views.py**

```
def login_view(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username,
                                password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                messages.info(request,'登入成功!')
                return redirect('index')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'帳戶無效或密碼錯誤! 請重試!')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'帳戶無效或密碼錯誤! 請重試!')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'customer/login.html',context)
```

**login.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="" style="position:absolute;top:300px;left:125px;">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        {{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}<br>
        {{ form.password|as_crispy_field }}<br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">登入</button>
</form>
```

For the login function in Django, I am trying to use the username and password based on the `User` model in `django.contrib.auth.models` to login into the account. However, even though I am using my superuser status to login and the error message appears showing that invalid username or password. May I ask is `AuthenticationForm` following the `User` model information to authenticate the user or anything I am missing?

Comment: AuthenticationForm will use any auth model (default or custom) that you have specified in your settings.py under `AUTH_USER_MODEL` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the 'data' attribute to the AuthenticationForm. Try this:

```
def login_view(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            login(request, form.get_user())
            messages.info(request,'登入成功!')
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'帳戶無效或密碼錯誤! 請重試!')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'customer/login.html',context)
```

The AuthenticationForm already does the authentication for you, so there is no need to run the `authenticate` function in your code again. You can get the user object for logging in using `form.get_user()` if the form is valid.